# Combining jquery validation errors in one DIV element

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have some form with jquery validantion, and i want to display all errors in same `div` element above the form.

i try do this, but is not working:

```
$("#contactForm").validate({
            rules: {
                assunto: { required: true },
                nome: { required: true, minlength: 2 }, 
                email: { required: true, email: true },
                telefone: { required: true },
                mensagem: { required: true }
            }, 
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if (element.attr("name") == "assunto" || element.attr("name") == "nome" || element.attr("name") == "email" || element.attr("name") == "telefone" || element.attr("name") == "mensagem" )
                //here i think i want to insert the location but i don't know how!
            else
                //here i think i want to insert the location but i don't know how!
            },

            messages: { 
                assunto: {required: 'É necessário escolher um assunto'},
                nome: { required: 'É necessário preencher o campo nome', minlength: 'No mínimo 2 letras' }, 
                email: { required: 'Informe seu email', email: 'Informe um Email válido' },             
                telefone: { required: 'Informe seu Telefone' },
                mensagem: { required: 'Escreva sua Mensagem' }
            },

            submitHandler: function(form){
                var dados = $( form ).serialize();  
                $.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    url: "enviafaleconosco.asp",
                    data: dados,  
                    success: function( data )  
                    {  
                        alert("Obrigado! Seu contato foi enviado com sucesso. Breve retornaremos!");
                        $("#contactForm")[0].reset();                   
                    }  
                });  
                return false;  
            }           
    });
```

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried debugging it? Are you doing a form submit to trigger the handler? do you have errors in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a Syntax error here:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if (element.attr("name") == "assunto" || element.attr("name") == "nome" || element.attr("name") == "email" || element.attr("name") == "telefone" || element.attr("name") == "mensagem" )
                //here i think i want to insert the location but i don't know how!
                else
                //here i think i want to insert the location but i don't know how!
            },
```

If the if and else don't have nothing inside you must add the curly brackets `{}` to close them:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if (element.attr("name") == "assunto" || element.attr("name") == "nome" || element.attr("name") == "email" || element.attr("name") == "telefone" || element.attr("name") == "mensagem" ){
                //here i think i want to insert the location but i don't know how!
                } else {
                //here i think i want to insert the location but i don't know how!
                }
            },
```

It is also a good practice to always add the curly brackets to if blocks, even if they are single line

Comment: thanks, i have fixed this! Now the errors ar showing but, how to insert these errors inside of a `div` ?

Comment: i have tried this: `error.insertAfter("#erros");` this insert the errors after the `div`, but i want the errors inside this `div`

Comment: @Preston is the `error` a jquery object? you can try `$("#erros").after(error);`

Comment: yeas, it is... i have found the the way: `error.appendTo($('#erros'));` thankz for help!